# C++ Qt: Connect a TextEdit with a Label

Tags: c++, qt

In a Qt GUI I'm trying to connect a TextEdit with a label so that when the user types something, the label updates it's text. Here is what I've tried:

```
void MainWindow ::updatelabel()
{
    ui->label->setText("Hello");
}

void MainWindow::changeTextColor()
{
    QString textEdit = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    QString label = ui->label->text();
    connect(textEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged()), label, SLOT(updateLabel()));
}
```

This gives me an error though:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::connect(QString&, const char*, QString&, const char*)'
     connect(textEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged()), label, SLOT(updateLabel()));
                                                                        ^
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few problems in your code. Here's changed code with comments explaining it:

```
// make sure updateLabel is declared under slots: tag in .h file
void MainWindow ::updatelabel()
{
    // set label text to be the text in the text edit when this slot is called
    ui->label->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText());
}

// this is a very suspicious method. Where do you call it from?
// I changed its name to better indicate what it does.
void MainWindow::initializeUpdatingLabel()
{
    //QString textEdit = ui->textEdit->toPlainText(); // not used
    //QString label = ui->label->text(); // not used

    // when ever textChanged is emitted, call our updatelabel slot
    connect(ui->textEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged()), 
            this, SLOT(updatelabel())); // updateLabel or updatelabel??!
}
```

---

A practical hint: when ever you use `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros, let Qt Creator to autocomplete them. If you type them by hand, and make a typo, you don't get a compile time error, instead there will be a runtime warning print about having no a matching signal/slot.

Or, assuming you are using Qt5 and C++11 capable compiler, you can use the new connect syntax, which will give you compiler error if you get it wrong. First add line `CONFIG += C++11` to the `.pro` file, and then do the connect like this:

```
void MainWindow::initializeUpdatingLabel()
{
    connect(ui->textEdit, &QTextEdit::textChanged, 
            this, &MainWindow::updatelabel);
}
```

Now if you for example actually have no `updateLabel` method, you get compile time error, which is much nicer than runtime message which you might not even notice. You could also replace the whole `updatelabel` method with a lambda, but that goes out of the scope of this question/answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're connecting to the wrong `textEdit` and `label` variables in that method:

```
-    connect(textEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged()), label, SLOT(updateLabel()));
+    connect(ui->textEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged()), this, SLOT(updateLabel()));
```

A `QString` is not a widget with signals and slots. You want the actual widget from `ui`, `ui->textEdit`, and `this` for the current class which contains `updateLabel()`.

Edits: fix mistakes I made because I answered while tired.

Comment: Thanks, this got rid of the error. But the new problem is that what i want to do doesn't actually work. If I type something, the label's text doesn't change. Would you know how to get this to work by any chance?